# Clear localstorage with Casperjs

Tags: javascript, local-storage, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to do some testings of a backbonejs application using localstorage.

My problem is that I can not clear the localstorage when testing with casperjs.

I have been trying to use `localStorage.clear();` at the beginning of my casper file but nothing is cleared.

Answer (score 7):

I found workaround for this problem by deleting file *.localstorage in one of the following directories:

Windows
c:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS\

Mac OS X: 
/Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Application Support/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS

Linux: 
/home/YOUR_USER/.local/share/data/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS

Answer (score 6):

What about running this after loading a page ?

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
  localStorage.clear();
}, {});
```

Comment: The issue I have with this solution, is that the page is already loaded based on the state of the local storage.  I'd like to clear it before the page loads, but casper errors out if I try that.  So, I'd have to load the page, clear local storage, then load the page again.

Comment: Or.....do this before loading the next page. If you have storage, it likely means you've already been to a page. Make a "noCacheNav" function that starts with this above script and then goes into the whole casper.thenOpen thing. That way it's a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS does not clear the localstorage correct.
localStorage.clear(); does not work (At least not reliable)

You have to delete the '.localstorage' File on the Filesystem.
The fs.remove Command has to be called before you open the Page. Phantomjs locks that file while the page is open.

I did it in our Project like that:

```
function clearStorage() {
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var myDomain = [I get this value from the commandline Parameter I give to CasperJS];

if(system.os.name === 'windows') {
    var userName = system.env['USERPROFILE'].split('\\')[2];
    var localstoragePath = 'C:/Users/' + userName + '/AppData/Local/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/';
    var localStorageFilename = myDomain.replace('://', '_').replace('/', '') + '_0.localstorage';
} else {
    var userName = system.env['USER'];
    var localstoragePath = '/home/' + userName + '/.local/share/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/';
    var localStorageFilename = myDomain.replace('://', '_') + '_0.localstorage'; //Linux does not have the last "/" so no replace needed for that
}

if(fs.exists(localstoragePath + localStorageFilename)) {
    fs.remove(localstoragePath + localStorageFilename, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            casper.echo(err);
        }
        casper.echo("File deleted successfully!");
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If on Linux user is root, then path would be: `/root/.local/share/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/`