# How do I clear the phantomjs cache on a mac?

Tags: javascript, caching, phantomjs, karma-runner, pouchdb

I somehow corrupted the phantomjs cache while testing with karma (writing [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com) tests). How can I clear this cache and get back to my original testing enviornment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took me days to figure this out so I figured I'd post it here, just

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS/*
```

I hope this saves someone else the hassle!

Comment: In ubuntu you can clear the cache with rm -rf ~/.qws/share/data/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was running into strange behaviors after having ran tests using PhantomJS' local storage (forgot to mock). Something was cached and I couldn't get rid of it. All the tests were failing cross branches, no matter what. Your solution to clear the cache of PhantomJS worked like a charm!

Comment: And on other systems, path seems to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687791/2873507