# How can we access files which were downloaded by PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to load a webpage through https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/ and was wondering

- How can I stop it from loading image files?
- How can I access the files already downloaded by PhantomJS?
- Why is a screenshot of PhantomJS different from what appears in my browser? Attached below

[image: From Chrome]
[image: From PhantomJS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I stop it from loading image files

You can pass the `--load-images=false` [commandline option](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) through the bridge to PhantomJS during creation:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create('--load-images=false', function (ph) {...});
// or
phantom.create({parameters: {'load-images': false}}, function (ph) {...});
```

or you can set it during the script through the [`page.settings`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html):

```
page.set("settings.loadImages", false);
```

> How can I access the files already downloaded by PhantomJS?

PhantomJS doesn't download any files into a customizable location if you e.g. click something. Instead it may put the downloaded files into cache. You can enable the disk cache through a commandline option (like above):

```
phantom.create('--load-images=false', '--disk-cache=true', function (ph) {...});
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687791/1816580) shows the default locations of the temporary files that PhantomJS creates.

> Why is a screenshot of PhantomJS different from what appears in my browser?

It could be anything. PhantomJS has a default viewport of 400x300 pixel (difference through media queries) and a user agent string different from your normal desktop browser. Websites may run some browser detection and feature detection scripts which can classify PhantomJS differently than your normal desktop browser. It could be anything, but changing the viewport size is probably sufficient:

```
page.set('viewportSize', { width:1280, height:800 });
page.set('settings.userAgent', 'some desktop user agent string');
```

Comment: I guess I was setting the UA and settings.loadImages incorrectly, but now everything seems to be working as expected expect temporary files.

Comment: I don't know if really all resources are cached and also, the cached resources are in a special format that you would need to parse. It's better to explicitly download some files with PhantomJS. If you have a specific problem with a site and script, please ask a new question.